# React native: Can't run project in iOS mode - Duplicate module name

Tags: ios, node.js, react-native, npm

I'm trying to run a react native project in iOS mode.

```
$ react-native run-ios
```

But I'm running in the errors

```
Failed to build DependencyGraph: @providesModule naming collision:
Duplicate module name: react-animated
Paths: /Users/mobile/node_modules/react-native-image-carousel/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Animated/release/package.json collides with /Users/mobile/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Animated/release/package.json

This error is caused by a @providesModule declaration with the same name across two different files.
Error: @providesModule naming collision:
Duplicate module name: react-animated
Paths: /Users/mobile/node_modules/react-native-image-carousel/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Animated/release/package.json collides with /Users/mobile/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Animated/release/package.json

This error is caused by a @providesModule declaration with the same name across two different files.
at HasteMap._updateHasteMap (/Users/mobile/node_modules/react-native/packager/react-packager/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/HasteMap.js:158:13)
at /Users/mobile/node_modules/react-native/packager/react-packager/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/HasteMap.js:133:31
```

I do not understand the problem and really need some help to get problem fixed.

---

This is how I've setup my system (macOS Sierra):

```
$ brew install node
$ brew install watchman
$ sudo npm install -g react-native-cli
$ npm install invariant --save-dev
$ npm install
```

Everything should be installed fine:

**versions**

```
$ node -v
  v4.0.0

$ react-native -v
  react-native-cli: 2.0.1
  react-native: 0.40.0

$ watchman -v
  4.7.0
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "~15.4.0-rc.4",
    "react-native": "0.40.0",
    "react-native-image-carousel": "^0.3.2",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^0.25.7",
    "react-native-local-mongodb": "^1.8.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "18.0.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "1.9.1",
    "invariant": "^2.2.2",
    "jest": "18.1.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "~15.4.0-rc.4"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

**npm list**

```
$ npm list --depth=0

├── babel-jest@18.0.0
├── babel-preset-react-native@1.9.1
├── invariant@2.2.2
├── jest@18.1.0
├── react@15.4.2
├── react-native@0.40.0
├── react-native-image-carousel@0.3.2
├── react-native-image-picker@0.25.7
├── react-native-local-mongodb@1.8.2
└── react-test-renderer@15.4.2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clear cache and start the project again.

Follow these steps to clear cache in your React Native package.

`watchman watch-del-all`

`rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-*`

`rm -rf node_modules/`

`npm cache clean`

`npm install`

`npm start -- --reset-cache`

Comment: After the last step I do get the error `Loading dependency graph...jest-haste-map: @providesModule naming collision:
  Duplicate module name: core-js
  Paths: /Users/mobile/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/core-js/package.json collides with /Users/mobile/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/fbjs/node_modules/core-js/package.json`

Comment: After `npm cache clean` do `yarn install && npm dedupe` and then restart the project. See if this works.

Comment: I works for the first run. But after closing Xcode and running `react-native run-ios` the application will not run in the simulator: `ld: library not found for -lRealmReact
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`